# finding rotated image coordinates

Tags: python

I'm using python and I have some images on my canvas that are rotated by different angles.
What I want to do is to get their coordinates while I know their previous position, axis and the angle they were rotated by.

It would also be enough if I can find coordinates of just one point after rotation

Comment: where is the center of rotation? A corner or the middle of the picture? Is the rotated version expanded in size or cropped to original size? (e.g. if a square is rotated by 45°, its "bounding box" gets increased by a factor of sqrt(2) in both directions)

Comment: The center of rotation is known. It may be different in different situations, but it would be enough with the center at the center of picture. The size is the same as in the original picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a coordinate after it has been rotated, I would use [numpy and a rotation](https://scipython.com/book/chapter-6-numpy/examples/creating-a-rotation-matrix-in-numpy/) matrix to derive its position:

[image]

```py
import numpy as np

# define parameters
pixel_column = 10
pixel_row = 20
center_column = 50
center_row = 50
# angle goes counter-clockwise!
rotation_angle_deg = 90


def get_rotation_matrix(angle_deg: float):
    theta = np.radians(angle_deg)
    cos_theta, sin_theta = np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta)
    rotation = np.array(((cos_theta, -sin_theta), (sin_theta, cos_theta)))
    return rotation


def rotate_coordinate(coordinate: np.array, angle_deg: float) -> np.array:
    rotation = get_rotation_matrix(angle_deg)
    rotated = rotation.dot(coordinate)
    return rotated


def get_new_coordinate(original_coordinate: np.array, center_of_rotation: np.array, angle_deg: float):
    delta = original_coordinate - center_of_rotation
    delta_rotated = rotate_coordinate(delta, angle_deg)
    new_coordinate = center_of_rotation + delta_rotated
    return new_coordinate

# calculate new rotated coordinate
rotated_coordinate = get_new_coordinate(
    np.array((pixel_row, pixel_column)),
    np.array((center_row, center_column)),
    rotation_angle_deg
)
new_pixel_row, new_pixel_column = [int(val) for val in rotated_coordinate]

# show as text
print(f"""
After rotating the image at an angle of {rotation_angle_deg}° around ({center_row}, {center_column}),
the pixel located previously at ({pixel_row}, {pixel_column}) is now at ({new_pixel_row}, {new_pixel_column}).
""")
```

Comment: I actually can't install matplotlib. Don't know why.

Comment: I have edited out the matplotlib usage in my code, so you can give this "reduced" version a try

Comment: Good job. It works well